# Ho to set minimum and maximum processor state on ubuntu?

Tags: power-management, cpu, cpufreq, intel-cpu

I would like to know how to set the minimum and maximum cpu state on ubuntu, like you do on Windows 10 on power settings. Just a way to control the MIPS and prevent CPU overheating when the thermal paste is a little bit worn out:

[Advanced Power Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdMVa.png)

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/822777/cpu-usage-ubuntu-14-04-16-10

Comment: I see, but isn't there any graphical interface?
Is the setting preserved after reboot?

Comment: Unlikey. These are not user settings but server related settings. And yes those are saved across reboots.

Answer (score 0):

For Intel processor to set minimum idle state to 1 do the following, presumably there are analogous parameters that can be passed by GRUB to the kernel for other CPU states and for Maximum, but I am no black belt in the subject:

sudo nano /etc/default/grub

then in that file change

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"

sudo update-grub
 sudo reboot

Comment: I would use `sudo nano -w /etc/default/grub `